# file not to be modifiyable by customer

Tags: java, configuration, external

I have a few configuration files (xml and xsl format) that my Java code uses. The customer shouldn't be able to tamper with these files. I don't have a problem with the customer being able to read these files, but they shouldn't be able to modify them.

Notes:

1. These files don't need to be visible to the customers, but it isn't a problem even if they can view them.
2. I should be able to give the customers a new set of configurations (if their requirement changes), so these files should be external to the WAR that I deliver.

Comment: There is not really a surefire way of achieving this; while you can alter file permissions since Java 7, it won't prevent alterations of said permissions by other processes

Comment: Get used to disappointment.

Comment: You put a comment in the file that says something like "The contents of this file should only be changed by <you or your organisation>. Changing this file yourself may result in the application behaving incorrectly and may cause loss of data. I/We will not be held responsible for any negative repercussions caused by unauthorised changes to this file." to make it clear that they shouldn't touch it, and that if they do, it's their fault if everything subsequently breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Just reread that you are the only one updating the files. Then you should use public private key encryption, such as RSA. That way you are the only one who can create or edit the config files.

Otherwise there is no easy way to achieve this. You can easily encrypt the files, or save a hash value of the files. The first will completely obscure the files making them unreadable, as long as the customers don't extract the encryption key from your program. The hash only works for verifying, so all it can do is to tell if the document has been tampered with.

All in all there is no way of keeping documents out of reach from your customers, as long as the documents are stored locally on your customers computers. You can only make it difficult for the customers, ensuring they don't do anything by mistake.

If you want truly secure files, you'll have to store them server side.

If you want your customers to read but not edit the files, you could save an unencrypted XML file along with the real encrypted file, but only read the encrypted.

Comment: If one wants customers to read but not edit the files, one can sign them.

Comment: hashing seems like a nice approach. Would i have to encrypt the hash value before storing  it or is there any better way to do this? (by encryption i  mean symmetric key, with key hardcoded in the java code. Although it isn't very secure, I don't mind hardcoding it)

Comment: You would need some way of ensuring that your customers wouldn't be able to recalculate the hash value. Maybe a hidden salt hard coded in your application. But if the config files are never changed client side, i would still refinement asynchronous encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same problem when I was making a program half a year ago. I realized that basically, I can't prevent that! So, I encrypted the file in my cipher, so that only my program could understand it and no one else! I suggest the same to you.

Like for example, if you **.xml** file has a node called **< money >** , you could rename the node as something which makes no sense i.e. something like **< wer >** and if it has amount **12000**, you could use **ab@@@** instead of 12000 (**a** for 1, **b** for 2, **@** for 0)

In this way, no one would understand what it means and would make no attempt to edit it!

Also, you could rename the file extension from **.xml** to **.mp3** or **.exe** so that they have no idea that it is your data file!

I did the same, and it worked!

Comment: seems like you are using a simple vernam cypher, this could be broken easily. Isn't this a concern or did I understand your answer wrong?

Comment: Actually vernam cipher is of much more complicated kind. This is just a simple one.
Also, who would understand that the node **< wer >** would contain the amount of money? Also, the extension change in the end prevents the file from being readable, unless the user is really advanced and /or opens every file in text editor!